# The output string returns as list. I want it to return a string

Tags: python-3.x

## What I've attempted

### Replace_program

```
strings = input("Write your string here: ") 

new_strings = [] 

for string in strings:

    new_string = strings.replace("not bad", "okay")

    new_strings.append(new_string)
    break;

print(new_strings)
```

## Expected output

Write your string here:

`'The movie yesterday was not bad'` should output `['The movie yesterday was okay']`.

Comment: so the first thing is you don't need a for loop to do this.simply the replace method will do the work. the second thing is you have initialised "new_strings" as a list that's why it is returning a list .

Comment: Well you always just add one item to the list so just take that item with `new_strings[0]`... (or better yet don't use a list at all `new_string = string.replace("not bad", "okay")`)

Answer (score 1):

1. **Try this:**

```
strings = input("Write your string here: ") 

new_strings = [] 

for string in strings:

    new_string = strings.replace("not bad", "okay")

    new_strings.append(new_string)
    break;

print("".join(new_strings))
```

You can use `.join` to return all list items to a string like this
if you have a list like this

`mylist = ['Hello', 'world']`  and `" ".join(mylist)` then output will be -> `Hello world`

also see this : [w3schools join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)

2. **or you can do this too**.

```
strings = input("Write your string here: ") 

new_strings = [] 

for string in strings:

    new_string = strings.replace("not bad", "okay")

    new_strings.append(new_string)
    break;

print(str(new_strings)[1:-1]) # if you don't like to print ' ' then you can fix it to print(str(new_strings)[2:-2])
```

this is string slicing. see this : [w3schools string slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp)

3: **and if you don't have to make a list you just have to do this**

```
strings = input("Write your string here: ") 
new_string = strings.replace("not bad", "okay")

print(new_string)
```

Comment: That `for` loop is useless (there is a `break` with no condition). I don't understand why you keep it in your code and don't say anything about it. All your answer should just be the last 3 lines of code

Comment: @Tomerikoo I just thought perhaps the question's owner will want to add some code to it later and need to have a list